# Android "gen" folder and SVN - bitter enemies

Tags: android, svn, version-control, tortoisesvn, intellij-idea

It seems that I accidentally checked in my "gen" folder from an Android project (this folder contains the R.java generated class).  When I realized I did this I deleted it from SVN and tried to ignore it.

Now I am now getting the error...

> "Could not add gen to the ignore list!
>   Working copy 'C:\code\guru' locked.

When I try to run a cleanup command I get this...

> Cleanup failed to process the
>   following paths:
>   -C:\code\guru 'C:\code\guru\gen' is not a working copy directory.

When I try to run a resolve I get this...

> Working copy 'C:\code\guru' locked
>   Please execute the 'Cleanup' command.

We are currently on SVN 1.6 on the server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try deleting the `gen` directory entirely from your checkout, then run Cleanup and then Update. If that doesn't work, you may have confused your Subversion client and you might have to make a completely new checkout. (Of course, don't delete your previous checkout until you've recovered anything in there you want to keep.)

Answer (score 3):

I rarely have any luck with Cleanup. I usually end up doing a completely fresh checkout and fixing any remaining problems there (carefully).